# Are sums extremal for subgaussian concentration?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-concentration

Bobkov and Houdre https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1178291721
showed that among all $f:R^n\to R$ that are $1$-Lipschitz
with respect to the $\ell_1$ metric,
the variance is maximized by sums. Namely, if $\xi_i$
are independent with variance $\sigma_i^2=\mathrm{var}[\xi_i]$, then
$$
\mathrm{var}[ f(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)]\le \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2.
$$

Motivated by this result, we ask the following question.
Let $\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)\in\{0,1\}^n$ have joint distribution $\mu$.
Suppose that $\mu$ satisfies the following property:
for all functions $f:\{0,1\}^n\to R$ of the form
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i),
$$
where $f_i:\{0,1\}\to[0,1]$,
we have
$$
P( |f(\xi)-E f(\xi)|\ge t) \le 2\exp(-Ct^2),
\qquad t\ge0,
\quad(*)
$$
where $P$ and $E$ are defined with respect to $\mu$
and $C$ depends on $\mu$ only.
For example, product measures satisfy $(*)$ with $C=2/n$.

Question: does $(*)$ necessarily also hold for all $1$-Lipschitz $f:\{0,1\}^n\to R$
(under the Hamming metric)?